# How to load only top 100 records, but not load all

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm using fluent nhibernate
And I want load some record from the table:

```
    public IQueryable<T> Load()
    {
        return Session.Query<T>();
    }
    public IQueryable<T> Load(Expression<System.Func<T, bool>> expression)
    {
        return Load().Where(expression);
    }
```

usage:

```
var list = repository.Load(a=> a.Id > 1000);
```

in case of huge table count of list is huge too, but I wont **only first (top) 100** (for example) records.

```
var list = repository.Load(a=> a.Id > 1000).Take(100);
```

Question: who to load top 100 records (using my *id* expression), but not loading all record (after 1100)?

Comment: Not sure if I get the issue.. why is `.Take(100)` NOT working?

Comment: @RadimKöhler according timewatch, both usage gives same time

Comment: what is the sql generated?  I've never had a problem with using Take() in a linq query with nhibernate before.

Answer (score 0):

I think you yourself have given the answer there, which is

var list = repository.Load(a=> a.Id > 1000).Take(100);

Take(100) would perfectly suffice your need. If your requirement is something else then specify with more clarity.